# Excel Charts Series function based on cell value

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

There is any way to plot a chart in excel based on a cell value ?

```
=SERIES('Sheet1'!$W$34;'Sheet1'!$A$35:$A$39;'Sheet1'!$W$35:$W$39;1)
```

Can we replace the params of the function with a string from another cell ?
Like that:

```
=SERIES($X$2)
```

Assuming that X2 contains a string

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. This is because SERIES() is in sheet formula, it's just function styled and only writing arguments for charts and alternative to chart creating form. And you can check this [link.](https://superuser.com/questions/913412/making-the-series-name-a-combination-of-text-and-cell-data) However you can use named ranges in it. Check [this link](http://exceltip.ru/files/43-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D1%8B.xlsx) to get example dynamic chart

Comment: Thanks for your response @bzimor I'll try to apply the named ranges approach.